# Google map embed won't load for some users: x-frame-options error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I created the following Google map for a client site:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?hl=en&authuser=0&mid=z57CojFvVAME.kEB7IkAVeA4M

Viewing privileges are set to public, and Google spits out some embed code.  When I use it, I can see it fine.  Users not logged in to Google can see it fine. Users logged in to some Google accounts, however, see the x-frame-options error below.

Refused to display 'https://admin.google.com/ServiceNotAllowed?service=mymaps&continue=https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid%3Dz57CojFvVAME.kEB7IkAVeA4M%26key%3DAIzaSyBctsDKeEdgLch0tn3FC-imJ3pn8kFhLrc' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I had suspected there to be a permissions error with this specific map, and so created and attempted embedding a new one, but got the same issues.  Any idea why this might be happening?  It doesn't seem to be browser-specific, and the usual hacks on stackoverflow (appending the url etc) don't do anything.

Here's an html page with the embed code:
http://bit.ly/1LC8aqm

I attempted recreating the map via the API, but it seems a rich map (with multiple data points) doesn't seem to embed that way. Ideas? Could it be a problem specific to my clients' domain?

Comment: It's just a guess, but maybe the affected users use a [google apps account](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/) where the particular app (mymaps) is not activated ...I don't think that you can do anything to solve it(as long as you use a embedded map). An option would be to create the map via the Javascript-API

Comment: @Dr.Molle I can't find an example of an API-driven map with these features.  I need to be able to have multiple data layers with multiple waypoints.  Any ideas if this can be achieved?

Comment: The features(layers) may be loaded via KMLLayer(see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603652/google-maps-api-google-maps-engine-my-maps/29604502#29604502) ...but the menu you'll have to create on your own.