# embedded google map change center or zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an embedded Google map (the kind you get an embedded iframe for using the Google maps site) with multiple markers on it. This is good so far as it goes but I need another function.

What I want to do is allow a person visiting the page to change to centre point by entering their postal code. I'd like them to also be able to change the zoom factor.

While there is massive amounts of documentation on using Google maps and on using the Google maps API, what I'm missing is a way to use the existing embedded Google map rather than creating a new blank map and populating it with markers.

The difference is important because it's quite easy to use the Google maps site to upload a .csv file with names and addresses that the Google map sorts out and displays. Doing the same thing with a blank map and javascript each time the page is loaded runs you up against the API transaction limits.

How can I tell the Google map API to connect to an embedded map instead of creating an empty one?

Comment: Maybe this interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603652/google-maps-api-google-maps-engine-my-maps/29604502#29604502

Comment: That looked interesting but it didn't work. After correcting the errors in the example that gave me a map with multiple world maps (they had .KmlLayer separated from the "new google.maps" and the KmlLayer should be kmlLayer), it doesn't seem to have done anything.

Comment: The example still works so I'm guessing that google maps doesn't like having a lot of markers on the map, which would run up against the transaction limits if each marker is added individually. Another explanation could be that google maps doesn't like its own .kml - something I've previously seen by trying to create a duplicate map from a .kml file I downloaded from an existing map.

Comment: It would be good to know which map you like to embed

Comment: it's https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zQ0ejZnSB8Ms.k8-dnaq9YqHE. This is a map of Lions recycle for sight eyeglass donation locations in the Greater Toronto Area. We want to expand it across Canada as a general sight for Canadian eyeglass donations. This requires being able to go beyond just the pan and zoom controls.

Comment: the approach with the KMLLayer will not work for this map, because the KML didn't contain coordinates: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zQ0ejZnSB8Ms.k8-dnaq9YqHE&nl=1&forcekml=1

Comment: Which doesn't help me because Google created the map from a .csv file I provided. It obviously calculated the coordinates and (I would hope) doesn't go through the process of recalculating each point every time someone looks at the map. It must be more computationally expensive to convert an address into a LatLng than it is to store the results of the calculation in whatever file it uses internally to produce the map.

Comment: Further to above, I have created a new map using a .kml file that contained the geographic coordinates that the old map displayed (interesting side note: we all talk about latitude and longitude but the kml coordinates are apparently longitude and latitude - I had to reverse them to stop the map from displaying points in Antarctica). However I can't use the new map either. Nor can I create new kmlLayer over a blank map using the kml file uploaded to a public web site. Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: what's the url of the KML-file?

Comment: The code I'm using is:   var myLayer = new google.maps.kmlLayer({
      url: "http://www.a711lions.ca/recycle.kml"
    });
  myLayer.setmap(map);  The javascript console gives me an error that google.maps.kmlLayer is not a constructor, but it seems to match the examples I've found in Google developer pages.

Comment: I'm not sure where the ";" is coming from after the kml file url. It's not in my code and I can't seem to remove it from the comment above. When I go to edit it, the ";" disappears. However, I can paste the code >{ url: "a711lions.ca/recycle.kml"; }< and it shows up.

Comment: The "http://www." vanished from my code above but it is there when I run it and I get the same error about kmlLayer not being a constructor. Weird editor - the "" earlier in this comment refers to h t t p : / / w w w . without the spaces. The editor on this site removed it too.

Comment: Never mind. It should have been KmlLayer.